# SQL server, Values of xml

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hola tengo un problema nesesito realizar esta consulta, la original es de oracle:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (
        xmltype (v.dsc_val),
           '/xmlCuentasLiquidacion/cuentasLiquidacion[id_prd="'
        || p_cod_producto
        || '"]/cuenta[moneda_pago="'
        || (SELECT ac.VALUE
              FROM atributos_configuraciones ac
             WHERE     aC.id_conf = t.id_conf
                   AND KEY = 'moneda_cta_cargo')
        || '"]/cuenta_pago')
    FROM base_bd_convenios.atributos a
     JOIN base_bd_convenios.valor_atributo va
        ON a.id_atr = va.id_atr
     JOIN base_bd_convenios.valores v
        ON va.id_val_atr = v.id_val_atr
    WHERE     a.cod_atr =
            'cuentaAbonoBancoLiquidacion'
     AND v.id_rec = p_cod_recaudador
```

Y debo realizar su migracion a sql server mi duda es como podria realizarla, intente con values pero no tuve suerte:

```
SELECT cast(v.dsc_val as xml).value(
                                '/xmlCuentasLiquidacion/cuentasLiquidacion[id_prd="' + cast(@p_cod_producto as varchar) + '"]/cuenta[moneda_pago="' +
                                 (SELECT ac.A_VALUE FROM BD_TARIFICACIONES.atributos_configuraciones ac WHERE aC.id_conf = t.id_conf AND A_KEY =                                            'moneda_cta_cargo') + '"]/cuenta_pago','nvarchar(max)')

                              FROM bd_convenios.atributos a JOIN bd_convenios.valor_atributo va ON a.id_atr = va.id_atr 
                                                            JOIN bd_convenios.valores v ON va.id_val_atr = v.id_val_atr 
                              WHERE a.cod_atr = 'cuentaAbonoBancoLiquidacion' AND v.id_rec = @p_cod_recaudador
```

Me indica el siguiente error:

> ```
> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal
> ```

entiendo que es debido al cast en la variable `"v.dsc_val"`, pero esta variable esta definida como text y sin el cast me arroja el siguiente problema:

> ```
> Cannot call methods on text
> ```

Comment: Haz probado usar Convert en ves de cast?

Comment: sep, me arroja el mismo error:The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal, por lo que asumo q estoy utilizando mal la funcion value

Comment: Es que cuando usas .value tiene que recibir un string, y creo que no lo esta haciendo

Comment: por eso hago el cast, aun asi no me genera la consulta de forma correcta